# Transactional outbox does not use the outbox when messages are published from a service class

Tags: masstransit

I'm using the latest version of MassTransit (8.0.5) and have been evaluating the transactional outbox feature. I've come across an issue and wanted to understand if it was a limitation of the current implementation of the outbox pattern.

In the following scenario, the outbox works as intended, it saves the published message to the outbox:

```
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SubmitOrderCommand> context)
    {
        await _dbContext.ConsumerAggregate.AddAsync(new ConsumerAggregate { Name = "abc" });

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        await context.Publish(new OrderSubmittedEvent("abcdef"));
    }
```

If I hover over the context object, i can see the PublishEndpointProvider is using the OutboxPublishEndpointProvider as expected.
[image: TransactionaloutboxIssue1]

However, if I use a service class to publish the message, this time using IPublishEndpoint, it does not use the outbox, which is not what I was expecting:

```
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SubmitOrderCommand> context)
    {
        await _dbContext.ConsumerAggregate.AddAsync(new ConsumerAggregate { Name = "abc" });

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        await _submitOrderService.DoWork();
    }
```

SubmitOrderService:

```
    public SubmitOrderService(IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
    {
        _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
    }

    public async Task DoWork()
    {
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new OrderSubmittedEvent("abcdef"));
    }
```

[image: TransactionaloutboxIssue2]

My service is registered in DI as a scoped service:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<SubmitOrderService>();
```

The reason this seems like a bug is because if I use the "UseInMemoryOutbox", my example works in both scenarios (publishing inside the consumer handler and also within a service method) :

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll create an issue, this is a bug.

Comment: Good catch, not sure how I missed it, but the next develop packages will have the fix and it will be in 8.0.6.

Comment: Great, thank you for the quick response, look forward to the next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug in the 8.0.5 MassTransit release, which has been [fixed](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/3577) for 8.0.6.